# jQuery vertical accordion menu onhover/onclick combination

Tags: jquery, menu, onclick, accordion, onhover

all
I am integrating a jQuery vertical accordion menu to be more specific [THIS ONE HERE](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-vertical-accordion-menu-plugin/examples/)

As you can see this nice easing menu is set to be hover or onclick function. 
What im trying to achieve here to use the combination of two: specifically i want the first and second child to open with onclick function and the third one with a hover.. i tried different techniques non of them seems to work so far, im pretty new in jQuery.. any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the third one, instead of keeping it part of the main accordion, add a second version of the accordion with its own settings

Comment: Actually this is the most simple and most effective solution which works perfectly:) Thanks!

Comment: no prob, sometimes it just takes another perspective :) cheers

Answer (score 0):

Default functionality doesn't support this behavior.
For more info take a look here http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/